# Add/Replace character in a section of a line

Tags: sed, addition

I would like to have your help on this:
I have these IPv6s:

```
29c4:fe34:5:2087:86b8:2ff:fed1:9f24

2c0f:f4b8:1:2092:51:6ff:fe81:c600
```

The sections are divided by ":" and I need to find groups that have less than 4 digits from fifth to eighth section and add "0"s to have something like this:

```
29c4:fe34:5:2087:86b8:02ff:fed1:9f24

2c0f:f4b8:1:2092:0051:06ff:fe81:c600
```

I have tried with sed, but not success... Honestly I have not idea how to do it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the `sed` solution:

```
sed -E ':l;s/^(([^:]+:){4,})(\b[[:xdigit:]]{1,3}\b)/\10\3/g;tl' inputfile
```

Result:

```
29c4:fe34:5:2087:86b8:02ff:fed1:9f24
2c0f:f4b8:1:2092:0051:06ff:fe81:c600
```

**[Explanation]**

- The command `:l` defines a label `l` to loop.
- The regex `(([^:]+:){4,})` will match leading four or more
  fields to reserve them unmodified.
- The next regex `(\b[[:xdigit:]]{1,3}\b)` will match hexadecimal value
  which is shorter than four digits.
- Then the `s` command will replace it by adding a leading zero with
  the expression `\10\3` which is a concatenation of \1, "0" and \3.
- The final `tl` command branches to label `l` if the `s` command
  succeeds. Then it tries next substitution.